# AWS RDS painfully slow when connecting from local machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS instance up and running. When the DB is queried from my website (also on AWS, same region) it runs beautifully. But, if I try to connect to the database from my local developments machine it takes AGES for any query to execute. Does anyone know why? I have opened up the security group to allow connections (while i try to connect from the local machine).

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? Connecting from my local machine using Postico works fine, from JDBC is the problem.

Comment: Nope. Still an issue.

Comment: Docs for JDBC - https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/93/connect.html - you can add loglevel = 2 to debug jdbc. If that works on other program, then probably something is configured in different way - like forced SSL. Please collect some logs to see what is going on.

Comment: I'm having the same issue for a very long time. Happens with RDS only

Comment: @MichałZaborowski can "forced SSL" in AWS be causing the slow performance?!

Comment: @dontdownvoteme nice nick. In general, this days - I would say - no. It makes connection slower - by default. Also, if you are reconnecting all over again - it can also slow things down, really much. But under normal circumstances - ssl start with asym, but then goes symmetric.

Comment: besides that can you traceroute? what software are you using? If structure is big... and it fetches whole DB? ;)

Comment: @MichałZaborowski I am fetching data which should normally take around 2-3 seconds in the web-hosted in AWS, but in localhost, it takes up to 1 minute. Internet speed is fast, bandwidth good enough, AWS server is located close, maximum connection is set to 300 which is just fine. Everything seems fine but still it's painfully slow.

Comment: how you are connecting to the server? directly? over bastion-host?

Comment: @MichałZaborowski I am connecting directly. I use PDO driver but I have tried with ODBC connection and I didn't notice any better performance.

Comment: @dontdownvoteme Can you setup Aurora, and check how it goes? That way you can tell if problem is with connection, or configuration. Also you can start psql with simple query and strace it - that can tell how your query is processed - well if you have Linux... If you use IDE it can call many queries, and that can stack up with other problems - like slower connection, or DNS issues, or anything like that...

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons for a problem like this. Some reasons might be so obvious, but mentioning them for the completeness of the answer. You have said that queries execute slow, so I assume that connection establishes successfully and there is no problem with Network ACLs, Security Groups etc.

**Reason 1: Your Internet Connection is too Slow**

This could be due to many reasons. See the following...

- Another device using your internet bandwidth
- You have some parallel downloads happening in your same device
- Your internet quota has exceeded
- ISP speed issues

For whatever reason, a problem like this will be solved after some time. Check your internet speed using [this](https://www.speedcheck.org/).

**Reason 2: Exceeding the maximum number of connections on RDS instance**

You could be hitting a limit on the maximum number of processes for MySQL. So, when you connect and issue any command, then if the number of processes allowed to run are saturated, then you have to wait and your request goes into queue. But if you don't get a slot then after that it timeouts.

The total number of connections depends on the instance type you are using. That you can check and set in the DB parameters group option. Search for `max_connections`.

[image]

**Reason 3: Geographical Network Latency**

Your website, being on the same region has a lower number of network hops to reach the RDS instance. But You local machine might take multiple hops to reach the RDS and return back. Generally AWS is pretty fast and has a stable network but you might notice latency issues for some protocols.

This is highly unlikely, but still could be a reason.

**Reason 4: Your network bandwidth is low**

To query for multiple records, your bandwidth might not be enough to return them in blazing speeds. Hence, you see the slowness in database queries.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like there is a problem with your internet connection? All the queries from your local workstation have to go from your home or office network, out to the internet and then to your AWS VPC. If you have a slow internet connection that will be a problem. There could also be issue with any local firewall in your home/office.

Comment: Seems that it’s much faster when I don’t run in debug mode. Still not blazing, but much faster. Seems like debug has something to do with it (VS2017)