# Painfully slow connection speed from local machine to AWS RDS PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl, rds

I've looked everywhere for an answer to this problem. I found a [similar (unanswered) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33141467/aws-rds-painfully-slow-when-connecting-from-local-machine) on SO but not related to Java or SSL issues.

Important Information:

- The database I connect to is PostgreSQL on RDS.
- I can actually connect to the DB (it takes about 3 minutes to establish the connection). After the connection is established, simple queries take between 15-120 seconds.
- The problem only happens when connecting from my code.
- Connecting from Postico (on the same machine) works perfectly.
- Deploying to AWS EC2 the exact same connection works perfectly.
- I have added the RDS certificates to the keystore.
- The RDS force_ssl parameter is set to true.
- Notice the  `+ "?ssl=true"` parameter at the end of the connection string.
- Tested replacing the domain by the direct IP (to rule out DNS problems). Same thing.

I suspect it has something to do with SSL but can't confirm it.

This is my connection (pretty standard):

```
    String dbUriString = ConfigUtils.getEnv("DATABASE_URL");

    URI dbUri = new URI(dbUriString);

    String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
    String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + ':' + dbUri.getPort() + dbUri.getPath() + "?ssl=true";

    ComboPooledDataSource datasource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

    datasource.setUser(username);
    datasource.setPassword(password);
    datasource.setJdbcUrl(dbUrl);
    datasource.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver");

    datasource.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    datasource.setMinPoolSize(5);
    datasource.setAcquireIncrement(1);
    datasource.setAcquireRetryAttempts(3);
    datasource.setInitialPoolSize(5);
    datasource.setTestConnectionOnCheckout(true);

    return datasource;
```

A little more information:

- It's a Play Framework application.
- Java 8.
- DataSource connector c3p0.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: where is your local and rds instance located? can you check the ping latency b/w them ?

Comment: Does `telnet <database host> 5432` or something like this also take a long time? Timeouts like this are usually about DNS timeouts while finding the host address and/or verifying the host identity in TLS. Incorrect reverse DNS zones are a common culprit; a slow / bad resolver in the list of `/etc/resolv.conf` or equivalent is another. I'd check this first.

Comment: Telnet connects right away. Im using Google' DNS servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. The strange thing is I can connect with no problems from other Database clients on my same machine and same network. @AmitK I know its not a latency problem since I can connect from other clients on the same environment.

Comment: if your local and server is continent away, your network latency plays a big role , also from local system, internet speed is less as compared to server network width.

Comment: Latency can account for some milliseconds. We are talking hundreds of times slower than expected.

Comment: Ruled out DNS issues by connecting directly to the IP of the server. Same sluggish connection.

Comment: Not experienced with the ComboPooledDataSource, but try a minimal pool of 1, or an immediate connection to exclude a problem on that side.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting to our Postgres database on AWS took up to a minute or two to estabilish a connection, then it worked fine.

The reason turned out to be DNS resolution.

I ran `telnet <database host> 5432` and discovered it was trying to connect to an IPv6 connection. After a minute or so, it would time out and try the IPv4 connection, which worked instantly.

Running `dscacheutil -q host -a name <database host>` on my macOS machine indeed showed the database host was resolved to an IPv6 and IPv4 address.

I changed the DNS settings on my machine. Specifically, I told my VPN client to use Google’s DNS servers for the amazonaws.com domain. After that, everything worked perfectly. Indeed, on rerunning `dscacheutil -q host -a name <database host>`, I only saw the IPv4 address this time.

No idea by the IPv6 connection wasn’t working, but the short of it was that DNS was part of the issue.