# Remote (localhost) connection and performance of AWS RDS is very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, server

I am experiencing the same issue as many of others have had (based on my research) but none of them seemed to have figured out a solution.

I am connecting from localhost to my AWS database (server located in Dublin - eu-west-1) and I am located in Denmark.

From my investigation I came to this conclusion that none of the above are the culprit:

- Internet speed I am using is 1GB/s so it is definitely not a problem!
- Bandwidth download - 500 GB, upload - 150 GB.
- Max connections to database is 312.
- Latency shouldn't be a problem as it is within the continent.

I referred to this post but couldn't find any of the posted solutions that fits my case [AWS RDS painfully slow when connecting from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33141467/aws-rds-painfully-slow-when-connecting-from-local-machine)

My queries are taking way too long (40+ seconds).

What could be causing it?!

**EDIT:**

- I currently am using PDO.
- I have tested it with ODBC connection, same problem there.
- If you are thinking that the amount of data is affecting it, that's wrong. I am fetching the same amount of data from the server hosted web but with a lighting speed.

Comment: Can you check from other computer, different network (home/work)?

Comment: @Marcin I did, same problem.

Comment: It might be due to the way your SQL client connects to the database and receives results. If there is lots of data coming back, it might be sending it in smaller amounts that require acknowledgement before sending more. Try using a different SQL client (and even a text-based command line client) to see if it works any better.

Comment: You need to spend some time to identify where the query is spending its time. You don't say which DBMS you're using, or which client-side library, so it's impossible to give you any specific advice. However, general advice is (1) look for a server-side query log to see if that's where the time is spent, and (2) measure the client-side time from submitting the query to retrieval of first and last rows.

Comment: Also provide some information about what the query is doing. Are you retrieving a single row based on primary key, or 10,000 rows using a complex join? What is your RDS instance type? What does the Monitoring tab show for memory and CPU usage?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I use PDO connection, I use the same in the web hosted at AWS but it is lightning fast there. It also has absolutely nothing to do with how many rows or how much data I am fetching because again, it is LIGHTNING fast in AWS hosted version.

Comment: @Parsifal please read my reply above, i gave an explanation there.

Comment: @Parsifal btw I have tested it with ODBC connection, nothing changed.